# Who to inform (in UK) following a divorce abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, divorce

I am a Brit living in Germany. I just received confimation of my divorce from the German court. (I was married in Germany to a German national and we have never lived in the UK during the marriage.) Attached to the document was a sticker telling me to inform the authorities in my country of the divorce.

I have just been searching fco.gov.uk for some info but cannot find any indication about who should be informed.

Who should be told?

Comment: Just to be clear - was the divorce done in the UK or in Germany?

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but I'm getting the impression that you don't need to notify the British authorities until you wish to remarry, in which case your certificate of divorce would be one of the documents you supply to the register office.

Comment: @PeterTaylor does taxation in the UK depend on marital status?

Comment: @Gagravarr - I reworded the question

Comment: @phoog If one of you doesn't work / doesn't work much, and the other isn't too well paid, [you can share some of your tax free allowance](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/family/marriage-tax-allowance), but if they're German residents then they wouldn't be covered as that's only for UK tax residents

Comment: @Gagravarr perhaps then the answer, given that the marriage was conducted in Germany and the couple lived in Germany, is "you should inform whatever authorities you informed about your marriage, if any."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sticker is presumably a reminder intended for, among others, people who were married in a foreign jurisdiction, so the records of the marriage can be amended with the information that the marriage has ended.  In your case, since you were married in Germany, that's not relevant to your "home country."

(Bureaucratic instructions like this often assume a certain set of circumstances without considering odd corner cases, or even cases that might be perfectly common, such as this.)

Since you weren't married in the UK, you should probably take this as a reminder to inform any UK authorities (or indeed any other authorities) whom you have informed of your marriage.  If there are no such authorities, then you can no doubt ignore the sticker entirely.